# this pointer, operator= and operator++

Tags: c++

assignment based around operator= copy overloading, and learning objects. coding operator++ for a class.

the instructions are:

```
Seti operator++( );
  This operator simply increases the value of a Seti object's frequency
  by 1 (to a maximum of 9), before returning a copy of itself.
    NOTE: The frequency can never exceed 9.
```

can i do this:

```
Seti Seti::operator++( ) {
    Seti temp;
    temp = *this
    if (temp.freq<9)
    temp.freq+=1;
    return temp;
}
```

thanks.

Comment: You should add what you expect to happen and what really happens.

Comment: i havent finished coding the assignment, i just wanted to know if that was legal. 

what should happen is the freq++ and a copy of the current object should be returned.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `C`?

Comment: You are confusing `operator ++()` and `operator ++(int)`. (Well, the assignment does.)

Comment: And the question is? (Do my homework for me?)

Comment: yes i apologize. sorry for my behaviour

Comment: No need to apologize. Just tell us your question …

Comment: can i do temp=*this; and will that make a copy of the current instance and assign it to temp according to my operator=?

Comment: Why don't you do `Seti temp = *this;`?

Comment: i did not know i could, i am very bad at this.. i will do that :)

Comment: @Kay: Think about `++seti` vs `seti++` some more, along with the required behavior.  I think your first comment is wrong.

Comment: @BenVoigt, well normally you'd assume `T &operator ++() { …; return *this; }`, wouldn't you?

Comment: @Kay: Yes, but the specification definitely requires returning by value. (I still would do `return *this;`, since that will make the required copy)  Oh I just realized you're talking about the return type, not the order of increment vs copy?

Comment: @BenVoigt my statement was that the text homework was awkwardly stated. It does not encourage a good coding style. Upd: Both, actually.

Comment: @Kay: I agree the clipping is non-standard behavior for preincrement and so it probably should be implemented as an ordinary function, not an operator overload.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't match the specified behavior, which is to increase the frequency of the object `operator++` is called on.

Comment: Sorry i wrote it quickly, just pretend i increased it before temp=*this

Comment: @user2125022: Instead of pretending, why don't you edit your question?

Answer (score 1):

`operator++()` is the **pre-increment** operator.  It is meant to modify the original object and then return a *reference to* the object after it has been incremented.  The reference allows code to continue accessing the original object from the return value directly, eg:

```
Seti s;
(++s).something // something applies to s itself, not a copy of s
```

`operator++(int)` is the **post-increment** operator.  It is meant to modify the original object and then return a *copy of* the object before it was incremented.  Since it is returning the object's previous state, it does not return a *reference to* the original object.

The declaration shown in your assignment suggests the **pre-increment** operator, since there is no input parameter.  However, the return value is supposed to be a reference.  The *correct* implementation would be:

```
Seti& Seti::operator++()
{
    if (this->freq < 9)
        this->freq += 1;
    return *this;
}
```

On the other hand, if you want to implement the **post-increment** operator, the *correct* implementation would be:

```
Seti Seti::operator++(int)
{
    Seti temp(*this);
    if (this->freq < 9)
        this->freq += 1;
    return temp;
}
```

When using the operators:

```
Seti s;
++s; // calls operator++()
s++; // calls operator++(int)
```

Section 13.5.7 of the C++ standard shows the official declaration of these operators:

```
class X {
public:
    X& operator++(); // prefix ++a
    X operator++(int); // postfix a++
};

class Y { };
Y& operator++(Y&); // prefix ++b
Y operator++(Y&, int); // postfix b++
```

Comment: These are the normal semantics.  They are not required.  If you still claim returning by reference is a requirement, please cite the Standard.

Comment: I downvote an answer when it says something is **required** when in fact it is only *good practice*.

Comment: Section 13.5.7 of the C++ standard shows the official declaration of the operators: `class X {
public:
X& operator++(); // prefix ++a
X operator++(int); // postfix a++
};
class Y { };
Y& operator++(Y&); // prefix ++b
Y operator++(Y&, int); // postfix b++`

Comment: Do you think that code snippet also means that classes must be named `X` and `Y`?  Or that operators can't have inline definitions?  Or is it just an example, with many possible variations?

Comment: The same section says "one parameter (which shall be of type `int`)".  Don't you think it would have stated that the return value "shall be a reference to the class type" if this were required?

Comment: I think that given there is only one code example and no such text verbage, then the code example is authoritive as to what the **declarations** must be. That also corresponds with the authoritive text verbage in section 13.6 for "built-in operators", which shows pre-increment for objects returning a reference and post-increment for objects returning a value.

Comment: Remy: Quite the contrary.  Any text bracketed by *[Example: -- end example]* is non-normative.  Ask any of the other language lawyers in the C++ chatroom.  Every one of them will tell you that the presence of an example doesn't exclude other return types.  Actual requirements are *always* in the text.